# How to resolve TranslationError: DeepL call resulted in a unknown result? Python Pydeepl

Tags: python, translation, deepl

I wanted to use pydeepl in order to translate some sentences on python. I have installed pydeepl and reproduced the same code as the main page of this library:

```
import pydeepl
sentence = 'I like turtles.'
from_language = 'EN'
to_language = 'ES'

translation = pydeepl.translate(sentence, to_language, from_lang=from_language)
print(translation)
```

Unfortunately I get this error: 
TranslationError: DeepL call resulted in a unknown result.

Can anyone help please? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the API is ONLY available if you pay, not free anymore...

Comment: There are actually both paid and free versions (https://www.deepl.com/pro#developer) of the API key, but the free version has a character limit.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: [DeepL Python Library](https://github.com/DeepLcom/deepl-python)
[MrGuemez](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7416390/) is partially right, requests only go through an official DeepL api key now. That being said, they have both [paid and free versions](https://www.deepl.com/pro#developer).

The DeepL free API has a 500,000 character/Mo. limit, whereas the paid version has a flat fee of $5/Mo., with an additional $20/20,000,000 characters. If you are worried about exceeding costs in the paid version, DeepL offers a cost control setting that you can set to make sure you don't exceed a certain monetary ceiling.
Not only is there now a free version of the API, there is an official DeepL Python Library:

Run a simple

```
pip install deepl
```

and you can get started very easily: if you don't care about hard-coding your auth_key you can declare a translator object as such:

```
translator = deepl.Translator("DEEPL_AUTH_KEY")
```

if you don't want to hard code it you can set it as an environmental variable this way: `translator = deepl.Translator(os.getenv("DEEPL_AUTH_KEY"))`)

You can then easily translate string text in like this:

```
# (Taken from the documentation)
# Translate text into a target language, in this case, French
result = translator.translate_text("Hello, world!", target_lang="FR")
print(result)  # "Bonjour, le monde !"
```

and multiple strings like this:

```
# (Taken from the documentation)
# Translate multiple texts into British English
result = translator.translate_text(["お元気ですか？", "¿Cómo estás?"], target_lang="EN-GB")
print(result[0].text)  # "How are you?"
print(result[0].detected_source_lang)  # "JA"
print(result[1].text)  # "How are you?"
print(result[1].detected_source_lang)  # "ES"
```

If you have a need to translate full documents, you can also pass those in:

```
translator.translate_document_from_filepath(
    "path/to/write/to/WhatABeautifulDay.docx", # Translated File
    "path/to/original/CheBellissimaGiornata.docx", # Original File
    target_lang="EN-US"
)
```

Just as a side note, the DeepL "EN" option is deprecated, and you must now use "EN-US" or "EN-GB" in your request.

---

OUTDATED (Still works for translating strings)

To use the api key in python you must structure a query as such:

```
import requests    
raw_returned_data = requests.post(
        url="https://api.deepl.com/v2/translate",
        data={
            "target_lang": "EN",
            "auth_key": auth_key, # where auth key is your api key
            "text": data # you can pass in a hard coded string or variable
        },
    )
```

And to view the response:

```
returned_data = raw_returned_data.json()["translations"][0]["text"]
```